# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist

Tags: database

[image][image]  i  i am moving the site form old domain to new domain,

i am getting error as like this :

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist

please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because of **database table**. Currently you are moving old domain to new domain. so please check your **database connection first.** After that make sure that you have **add all your database's tables**.

This error currently show that table name

> "sales_flat_order"

is not created in your database. so export

> sales_flat_order

from old domain and import it into new domain.